# How can we check if a file Exists or not using Win32 program?

Tags: windows, winapi, file

How can we check if a file Exists or not using a Win32 program? I am working for a Windows Mobile App.

Comment: std::filesystem::exists() C++17 onwards

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can call [`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Here is a sample I just knocked up:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int fileExists(TCHAR * file)
{
   WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
   HANDLE handle = FindFirstFile(file, &FindFileData) ;
   int found = handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
   if(found) 
   {
       //FindClose(&handle); this will crash
       FindClose(handle);
   }
   return found;
}

void _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
   if( argc != 2 )
   {
      _tprintf(TEXT("Usage: %s [target_file]\n"), argv[0]);
      return;
   }

   _tprintf (TEXT("Looking for file is %s\n"), argv[1]);

   if (fileExists(argv[1])) 
   {
      _tprintf (TEXT("File %s exists\n"), argv[1]);
   } 
   else 
   {
      _tprintf (TEXT("File %s doesn't exist\n"), argv[1]);
   }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to call `FindClose`. And you can't return a value from a void function.

Comment: Half corrected. You need to check for FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY.

Comment: See other answers for better ways to do this. Also, the code won't even compile as-is due to argv[1] being used in fileExists();

Comment: Poor solution; `GetFileAttributes()` is much better.

Comment: `GetFileAttributes` is a one liner

Comment: Suppose `file = "*"`, this might return `true` even if there isn't a file called *

Answer (score 227):

Use [`GetFileAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to check that the file system object exists and that it is not a directory.

```
BOOL FileExists(LPCTSTR szPath)
{
  DWORD dwAttrib = GetFileAttributes(szPath);

  return (dwAttrib != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES && 
         !(dwAttrib & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY));
}
```

Copied from [How do you check if a directory exists on Windows in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218325/how-do-you-check-if-a-directory-exists-on-windows-in-c)

Comment: +1 because of a short code example. Code examples are a time saver to get started.

Comment: I would like to note that your function returns bool and not BOOL.

Comment: For C++ yes, for C, it's a BOOL

Comment: Does this also deliver the best performance in file existence checking ?

Comment: @Bitterblue: Yes, this is as fast as I've been able to find.

Comment: The expression returns bool in C++ so bool return is fine.

Comment: Although it is possible that `GetFileAttributes()` might return `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES` due to error conditions other than the file does not exist.

Comment: "Related"? "Copied from".

Comment: Not an exact dupe :)

Answer (score 39):

You can make use of the function [`GetFileAttributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364944(v=vs.85).aspx). It returns `0xFFFFFFFF` if the file does not exist.

Comment: Interesting history on GetFileAttributes and why it is the preferred method in Windows code by Raymond Chen: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/10/23/5612082.aspx

Comment: You need to check for the object being a directory.

Comment: Actually it returns `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES` if the file not exists. On 64-bit it could be `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: @AndreasSpindler, Since the return type is `DWORD` how it can return `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` ?

Comment: Updated link to Raymond Chen's blog: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071023-00/?p=24713

Answer (score 20):

How about simply:

```
#include <io.h>
if(_access(path, 0) == 0)
    ...   // file exists
```

Comment: Pierre How did you find this function ? any reference ?

Comment: @Buddhika Chaturanga I started using it in Borland Turbo C, back in the 80's. It was the only way to check for the presence of a file, before the fancier "CreateFile". It's buried in the Visual Studio documentation.

Comment: I had to use if (_waccess(path.c_str(), 0) == 0)... works like a charm for folders and files, thank you @Pierre

Answer (score 10):

Another option:  ['PathFileExists'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

But I'd probably go with `GetFileAttributes`.

Comment: In addition `PathFileExists` requires the use of "Shlwapi.dll" (which is unavailable on a few windows versions) and is slightly slower than `GetFileAttributes`.

Comment: But it doesn't tell you if a file or directory existed.

Comment: BTW, PathFileExists is just a wrapper for GetFileAttributes with additional SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS) wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Came across the same issue and found this brief code in another [forum](https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?285435-which-API-can-check-if-a-file-exists-or-not) which uses [GetFileAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesa?redirectedfrom=MSDN) Approach

```
DWORD dwAttr = GetFileAttributes(szPath);
if (dwAttr == 0xffffffff){

  DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
  if (dwError == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
  {
    // file not found
  }
  else if (dwError == ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND)
  {
    // path not found
  }
  else if (dwError == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
  {
    // file or directory exists, but access is denied
  }
  else
  {
    // some other error has occured
  }

}else{

  if (dwAttr & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
  {
    // this is a directory
  }
  else
  {
    // this is an ordinary file
  }
}
```

where `szPath` is the file-path.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to open the file. If it failed, it means not exist in most time.

Comment: I'd go with CreateFile -> CloseHandle. easiest and cheapest.

Comment: A file open can also fail if the files exists but the user does not have sufficient privileges to open the file. These days, that's a **very** common situation.

Comment: Not to mention it is not the cheapest because the file can be on a network share which adds latency for each call and with CloseHandle you have two calls instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `OpenFile` with `uStyle` = `OF_EXIST`

```
if (OpenFile(path, NULL, OF_EXIST) == HFILE_ERROR)
{
    // file not found
}
// file exists, but is not open
```

Remember, when using `OF_EXIST`, the file is not open after `OpenFile` succeeds. Per Win32 documentation:

| Value | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| OF_EXIST (0x00004000) | Opens a file and then closes it. Use this to test for the existence of a file. |

See doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-openfile

Answer (score -2):

Another more generic non-windows way:

```
static bool FileExists(const char *path)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fpos_t fsize = 0;

    if ( !fopen_s(&fp, path, "r") )
    {
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
        fgetpos(fp, &fsize);
        fclose(fp);
    }

    return fsize > 0;
}
```

Comment: if you're going to use fopen et al. you may as well just use `_access(0)`.

Comment: @RobK This has the minor advantage of being cross-platform whereas _access is not. The real problem is that it will return that zero-length files don't exist...

Comment: fopen_s is Microsoft specific, and in addition to 0 byte files being declared non-existing by this broken code it also fails on files it can't open (permissions, sharing).