# How to check if directory exist using C++ and winAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, directory

How do I check whether a directory exists using C++ and windows API?

Comment: why not just do `BOOL PathFileExists(pszPath);`  as shown in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773584(v=vs.85).aspx  ?

Comment: Since C++ 17 one doesn't have to rely on platform-specific API's for this: `std::filesystem::exists(dirPath) && std::filesystem::is_directory(dirPath)`. See [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem).

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Here is a simple function which does exactly this :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

bool dirExists(const std::string& dirName_in)
{
  DWORD ftyp = GetFileAttributesA(dirName_in.c_str());
  if (ftyp == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES)
    return false;  //something is wrong with your path!

  if (ftyp & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
    return true;   // this is a directory!

  return false;    // this is not a directory!
}
```

Comment: `GetFileAttributes()` returns `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES` when a failure occurs. You have to use `GetLastError()` to find out what that failure actually is. If it returns `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`, `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`, `ERROR_INVALID_NAME`, or `ERROR_BAD_NETPATH` then it really does not exist. But if it returns most any other error, then something actually exists at the specified path but the attributes are simply not accessible.

Comment: For those stumbling on this answer, keep in mind that the above code is ANSI not Unicode.  For modern Unicode, it's better to take a LPCTSTR parameter such as the snippet in this other stackoverflow answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6218445.  (The LPCTSTR will be translated to `wchar_t*` by the compiler.).  You can then wrap that Unicode-aware function to take a C++ `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`.

Answer (score 10):

If linking to the shell Lightweight API (shlwapi.dll) is ok for you, you can use the [PathIsDirectory function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773621%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

This code might work:

```
//if the directory exists
 DWORD dwAttr = GetFileAttributes(str);
 if(dwAttr != 0xffffffff && (dwAttr & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
```

Answer (score 2):

0.1 second Google search:

```
BOOL DirectoryExists(const char* dirName) {
  DWORD attribs = ::GetFileAttributesA(dirName);
  if (attribs == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES) {
    return false;
  }
  return (attribs & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY);
}
```