# How to check whether a directory is shared?

Tags: c#, c++, c, windows

How can I check in C# whether a directory is shared? 
And is it done in C/C++ under Windows?

The directory is on the same PC!

Comment: What do you mean with shared? FIle share?

Comment: Do you mean shared as in shared on the network (i.e. "network share")?

Comment: Network share, and yes, in all 2 (3) language

Comment: C/C++ is not a language; so 3.

Comment: But you use the same Win32 API to find that out!

Comment: C and C++ are different languages though, not the same.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136539/determining-if-a-folder-is-shared-in-net

Comment: What now, a network share or do you want the attributes of a local folder!?

Comment: The attribute of a local folder, that it shared is

Comment: If you know that you do it using the Windows API in C and C++, then why do you ask how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for C#: To check wether you can access (read access at least) a network  share / unc path with the current logged in user, do a `IO.Directory.Exists(@"\\YourUNCShare")`

For C++:

[Check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233842/how-to-check-if-directory-exist-using-c-and-winapi)

There's also [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) MSDN article, using `PathFileExists` which should do for `C`.

Answer (score 1):

In C++/C# you can use the following windows API's
[NetShareEnum()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525387%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [NetShareGetInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525388%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Check MSDN for the details.