# How to check if a string given as input is a valid directory in C++ using Boost Libraries?

Tags: c++, string, boost, directory-structure

I am using Dev-C++ Ide for coding and I want to check if a string given as input is a valid existing directory or not in C++, I referred to these posts on StackOverflow but I couldn't find a solution that I could understand - [How to check if directory exist using C++ and winAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233842/how-to-check-if-directory-exist-using-c-and-winapi(this) one returns true in all case so no use) can anyone help me out with this problem?

Comment: Give code, expected output, your actual output. Also, depending on what version of Dev-C++ you have installed, it may be severely outdated.

Comment: Are you suggesting that a winapi call does not work?  Sounds a little unlikely, given the amount of testing it has had...

Comment: `I couldn't find a solution that I could understand `  So how are we to know what you understand?  The solutions given at that link were very simple, especially the one that got a rep of 30.

Comment: I am new to using this so can you like tell me given the input as a string parameter how to tell if its a directory or not?

Comment: @AnkitSablok - The solution is right there on the page you have a link to.  It is the very first answer -- it didn't get 30 upvotes for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this useful : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773584%28VS.85%29.aspx

Pasting example :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include "Shlwapi.h"

void main(void)
{
    // Valid file path name (file is there).
    char buffer_1[ ] = "C:\\TEST\\file.txt"; 
    char *lpStr1;
    lpStr1 = buffer_1;

    // Invalid file path name (file is not there).
    char buffer_2[ ] = "C:\\TEST\\file.doc"; 
    char *lpStr2;
    lpStr2 = buffer_2;

    // Return value from "PathFileExists".
    int retval;

    // Search for the presence of a file with a true result.
    retval = PathFileExists(lpStr1);
    if(retval == 1)
    {
        cout << "Search for the file path of : " << lpStr1 << endl;
        cout << "The file requested \"" << lpStr1 << "\" is a valid file" << endl;
        cout << "The return from function is : " << retval << endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "\nThe file requested " << lpStr1 << " is not a valid file" << endl;
        cout << "The return from function is : " << retval << endl;
    }

    // Search for the presence of a file with a false result.
    retval = PathFileExists(lpStr2);

    if(retval == 1)
    {
        cout << "\nThe file requested " << lpStr2 << "is a valid file" << endl;
        cout << "Search for the file path of : " << lpStr2 << endl;
        cout << "The return from function is : " << retval << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nThe file requested \"" << lpStr2 << "\" is not a valid file" << endl;
        cout << "The return from function is : " << retval << endl;
    }
}

OUTPUT
==============
Search for the file path of : C:\TEST\file.txt
The file requested "C:\TEST\file.txt" is a valid file
The return from function is : 1

The file requested "C:\TEST\file.doc" is not a valid file
The return from function is : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Portable solution using [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm):

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

//...

boost::filesystem::path dir(directory_path_string);

if (boost::filesystem::is_directory(dir) && boost::filesystem::exists(dir))
{
    // directory exists
}
```

Comment: okk yeah, I have installed boost, when I try to #include <boost/filesystem.hpp> it reports an error saying there is no such file can you point me to some reference which tells me how to use boost in dev c++?

Comment: @AnkitSablok You need to point Dev-C++ to your boost includes.

Comment: @AnkitSablok Strange you said you were new to this in your earlier comment, but seem to be able to want to use boost.

Comment: Menu bar -> Tools -> Compiler options -> Directories -> C++ Header files: Add path you the main directory of Boost

Comment: I am new to using Boost actually it is my first time :), so thats why I want to do it I checked out in earlier stack overflow posts regarding Boost

Comment: Please remember also to first build your boost libraries

Comment: Piotr S. - how to do that can you tell?

Comment: @AnkitSablok Then you should reword your original question to use `boost` only.  Otherwise, the solution you're looking for is a simple call to `GetFileAttributesA` and checking the "directory bit" on the return value.  It is the same solution given to you on the page you linked to in your question.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie : Ok, I will change it

Comment: @Ankit For information on how to build boost on your platform, refer to the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/more/getting_started/index.html). For a live example that demonstrates this working code, see [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9743a25c3728b98c). Remember to link against `boost_filesystem` and `boost_system` which must be built before you can use them.

Comment: @AnkitSablok  Since C++17 no need to use boost.  <filesystem> is part of std now.

Answer (score 0):

Try `boost::filesystem`:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

if ( !boost::filesystem::exists( "my_directory" ) )
{
  std::cout << "Can't find my directory!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Use  #include <filesystem>. It is in C++17.