# Is the behaviour of ifstream::ifstream on directories well-defined?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

*According to the C++11 standard*, is the behaviour of

```
ifstream in(".");
```

specified, or is it system-dependent?

For context, I'm trying to avoid using `boost::filesystem` and similar libraries because they cause unrelated portability problems.

Edit: According to what I can find, I should get a valid ifstream (one that is 'good()' if and only if the directory exists. This potentially gives a more portable way of testing whether a directory exists than using `boost::filesystem` because the latter requires you to link against more libraries.

Comment: A directory isn't a file.

Comment: What do you expect it to do?

Comment: A directory IS a file on Unix. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197439/how-is-a-directory-a-special-type-of-file

Comment: What I expect it to do is to return an ifstream that is good() if the directory exists. Editing q. .

Comment: Use [`<filesystem>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) instead?

Comment: @NathanOliver There's a reason I specified C++ 11…

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the tag in the title.  I've edited it to remove the tag from the title and instead tag the Q with [tag:c++11]

Comment: "A directory IS a file on Unix." - but not on other OSs - so this must be at best system-dependent.

Comment: Saying that a directory is a file in Unix is somewhat misleading as they don't support all the same operations, and in any case not relevant here because your question is about portable C++ and not Unix.

Comment: @interjay let me be more specific. The C++ 11 standard refers to fopen.  
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html gives something that looks like a spec. for fopen, but I think it's POSIX-specific.  Do you know where I can find a specification for fopen?

Comment: Even in unix, you are only supposed to open directories using specific options, which don't map easily onto FILE* or std::stream. So easy answer is no.

Comment: @GemTaylor note http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html clearly allows use of fopen on directories. E.g. see error EISDIR which prevents opening of dirs with write access.

Comment: The portable reference for `fopen` is the C standard, which doesn't say it can open directories. What you linked to is the POSIX version which has some extensions.

Comment: The C++ standard doesn't mention directories or Unix at all. If you want your program to work on Unixes, you need something that guarantees you behaviour on Unixes. The C++ standard isn't such a document. In practice you are likely to get a `good()` stream if you specify `std::ios_base::in` as the open mode. You are not likely to get any good `read`s from it though.

Comment: Also, The opening line clearly says file, and there are no instances of dir except for parent directory and direction. Try again.

Comment: @GemTaylor Try searching for "The named file is a directory and mode requires write access."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard does not seem to have a mention of the concept of a "directory" anywhere in its prose. There is a mention of the EISDIR errno and a general intention to mirror posix, but only "may use to report low-level conditions". I would say system-dependent and not portable.

Comment: The Committee is looking to correct this at some point. There is a technical specification to address it. Programming Languages — C++ — File System Technical Specification http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4100.pdf but it looks like it did not make it into C++17.

Comment: @RichardChambers interesting. That states unambiguously that a dir is a file.

Comment: @Mohan it might be better to think of it as the `filesystem` technical spec says that the `filesystem` function presents a directory as a file. Who knows what the underlying operating system OS is doing and what hoops the Standard Library jumps through under the hood in order to present an interface to that specification.

Answer (score 0):

> According to what I can find, I should get a valid `ifstream` (one that is `good()` if and only if the directory exists.

That result is not guaranteed by the standard. I wouldn't use it as a mechanism to check whether a directory exists.

When you are limited to using C++11, your best option is use to platform dependent API calls surrounded by appropriate preprocessor macros.

```
#if  defined(_WINDOWS)
// Use Windows specific APIs
#elif defined(_Linux)
// Use Linux specific APIs
#elif defined(_MacOS) ???
// Use MacOS specific APIs
#endif
```

More info:

For Windows: [How do you check if a directory exists on Windows in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218325/how-do-you-check-if-a-directory-exists-on-windows-in-c)
For Linux: [Checking if a directory exists in Unix (system call)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828192/checking-if-a-directory-exists-in-unix-system-call)