# Listing a directory's content and checking if the element is a file or a directory (C)

Tags: c, directory, filesystems

I've been trying to find a way to map a directory's content plus a check whether the found "element" is either a file or a directory.

I've tried all the "solutions" found here:
[How can I check if a directory exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12510874/how-can-i-check-if-a-directory-exists), [How do you check if a directory exists on Windows in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218325/how-do-you-check-if-a-directory-exists-on-windows-in-c) and [Checking if a file is a directory or just a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553012/checking-if-a-file-is-a-directory-or-just-a-file)

(My post here is not a duplicate, therefore)

Nothing was working for me. I'm on Windows 10. I'm not a fan of these windows libraries, anyway. That's why I'm looking for a way that only standard C. 
Here's my code so far:

```
struct dirent *de;
DIR *dr = opendir(opts->dirname);

#define DF_ISDIR 0x100
#define DF_ISFILE 0x200
#define DF_NOEXIST 0x400


while ((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL) {
    int exists = df_isdirectory(de->d_name);
    printf("[%s]: '%s'\n", exists == DF_ISDIR ? "DIR" : exists == DF_ISFILE ? "FILE" : "WHATEVER", de->d_name);
}
```

and

```
int df_isdirectory(const char *name) {
assert(name != NULL);

DIR *dp = NULL;
if (_access(name, F_OK) == 0) {
    if ((dp = opendir(name)) != NULL) {
        closedir(dp);
        return DF_ISDIR; //  element is directory
    } else {
        return DF_ISFILE; // element is a file
    }
}

return DF_NOEXIST; // element is whatever
```

}

It gives me the folliwing output:

[image]

As we can see, the program detects that .. and . as dirs, but not a single element in my directory. Even though "another" and "dfgsdgf" ARE DIRECTORIES!

[image]

So, why doesn't it consider my actual directories a directory?
Side note: One directory ("dfgsdgf") is empty, the other one ("another") is filled with 2 files.

After spending so much time, and trying a ton of "working" solutions, I am slowing getting tired of this. I want a detailed explanation WHY MY CODE DOESN'T WORK AS EXPECTED and a clear code snippet THAT WORKS 100%.

PS: My testing dir is C:\test
My exe file is not located in the same directory.

Thanks, and have a nice day!
~Sebastian

Comment: I'm no Unix expert, but the `dirent` struct has a `d_type` member. Did you check that?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp You do not need to be a unix expert to answer a windows question ;)

Comment: `_access(name, F_OK)` is a [TOCTOU bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use).  Such a check has no purpose and is not definitive - there are ways for `access()` to work and then `opendir()` fail on an actual directory.  If you need to know why `opendir()` fails, check `errno`.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you open the directory given in your `opts` structure:

```
DIR *dr = opendir(opts->dirname);
```

the content of `opts->dirname` is `C:\test`. However, here:

```
if ((dp = opendir(name)) != NULL) {
```

you try to open a directory entry *relative to your cwd* (which is somewhere else). Indeed already your `_access()` check fails due to that.

Try calling

```
chdir(opts->dirname);
```

before your `while()` loop or build a full path in a string to pass it to `_access()` and `opendir()` in your `df_isdirectory()` function.

Comment: Yeah, that worked, thanks! I just appended my "dirname" to the found file names in the while loop and passed the modified string instead of de->d_name!