# How to check if relative path exists

Tags: winapi

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6218445/1197719) it is suggested to use `GetFileAttributes()` to check if a directory exists. But apparently, `GetFileAttributes()` can succeed even if it is passed an invalid path.

For example, let's assume the current directory is `D:/test` but doing the following still doesn't return `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES` although the path passed to `GetFileAttributes()` clearly doesn't exist because there are way too many levels of `..`:

```
DWORD attrs = GetFileAttributes("../../../../../../..");
```

So how can I detect if a path actually exists?

Comment: question wrong asked. the `GetFileAttributes` work correct and the best solution here for check. but how convert relative name to nt-path ? here problem not in `GetFileAttributes` but in path conversation. try `RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U_WithStatus` and look to what converted your `"../../../../../../.."`. to the \??\D:\ anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But apparently, `GetFileAttributes()` can succeed even if it is passed
>   an invalid path.

this is wrong. if path really invalid - `GetFileAttributes` return appropriate error (`ERROR_INVALID_NAME` or `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` usually). not also that need check for `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION` and `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` in case `GetFileAttributes` return `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES`. because win32 convert to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` not only `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` but many other unrelated status - more correct use [`NtQueryAttributesFile`](https://www.google.com/search?q=NtQueryAttributesFile&client=aff-maxthon-maxthon4&channel=t27). also exist undocumented

```
extern "C" NTSYSAPI BOOLEAN NTAPI RtlDoesFileExists_U( _In_ PWSTR FileName );
```

which do this job (internal it call [`NtQueryAttributesFile`](https://www.google.com/search?q=NtQueryAttributesFile&client=aff-maxthon-maxthon4&channel=t27) and check also for `STATUS_SHARING_VIOLATION` AND `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`)

also after api return - file already can be deleted (or created) - as result returned value can be already wrong. so usual if we need some file/folder - need not try check but create or open it. or get error in this operation

---

but really your problem not in `GetFileAttributes` but in win32 to nt path conversion.

you assume that path `D:/test../../../../../../..` is wrong. but system think that not. the `RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U_WithStatus` (or related) used by system for convert win32 path to nt. if test this api with your path, this give:

```
UNICODE_STRING us;
if (0 <= RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U_WithStatus(L"D:/test../../../../../../..", &us, 0, 0))
{
    DbgPrint("%wZ\n", &us);
    RtlFreeUnicodeString(&us);
}
if (0 <= RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U_WithStatus(L"../../../../../../..", &us, 0, 0))
{
    DbgPrint("%wZ\n", &us);
    RtlFreeUnicodeString(&us);
}
```

`\??\D:\` and `\??\<X>:\` so system convert this to root folder on drive. and this folder exist.

Comment: So I have to manually check if the level of `..` is valid against the current directory because Windows apparently chooses to ignore all `..` beyond the root volume and treat it as a valid path?

Comment: @Andreas - i not think that. in this case your conversion will be conflict with system provided. what is your final target ?

Comment: Right, there seems to be some sort of convention among operating systems that superfluous occurrences of `..` are just ignored and that such constructions aren't invalid paths because Linux and macOS show the same behaviour as Windows so this seems to be some sort of convention that I wasn't aware of. I was of the opinion that an out-of-range number of `..` would construct an illegal path but apparently that's not the case so I can just leave everything like it is.